# How to keep the values in select control after loading of form?

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I'm having a form on which some HTML and Javascript code is written. I've written one function in jQuery which is set to run in document,ready(). When the page is loading the control shows the values returned by the function but as soon as the page loading is complete the values get disappear. I couldn't understand why this is happening? Can you have any clue on this to avoid such replacement of values on form loading completion? Thanks in Advance.

HTML code is as follows:

```
<li>
    <label>country<strong style='color:red'>*</strong> :</label>
    <div class="fl">
        <select onchange="print_state('user_state',this.selectedIndex,'{$data.user_state}');" id="user_country" name="user_country" class="sel"></select>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <label>State<strong style='color:red'>*</strong> :</label>
    <div class="fl">
        <select name="user_state" id="user_state" class="sel"></select>
    </div>
</li>
```

Javascript code is as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    print_country(user_country, India, Maharashtra);    
});
```

Comment: post your code, please

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
windows.load=function(){

         print_country(user_country, India, Maharashtra);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but where should I write this code in my file?